# Field is of type Object after retrieving from MDX

Tags: mdx, pentaho-report-designer

My MDX contains already the `NON EMPTY` keyword , but in the report I still get the field as of type `object` because the first line is empty in the OLAP :

```
select NON EMPTY Hierarchize(Crossjoin({[Measures].[engagement]}, Union(Union(Union(Union(Crossjoin({[structure].[All structures]}, {[temps].[2016]}), Crossjoin({[structure].[All structures]}, {[temps].[2015]})), Crossjoin({[structure].[All structures]}, {[temps].[2014]})), Crossjoin({[structure].[All structures]}, {[temps].[2013]})), Crossjoin({[structure].[All structures]}, {[temps].[2012]})))) ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {[soa].[00-01-0-030-00000], [soa].[00-01-0-100-00000], [soa].[00-01-0-120-00000], [soa].[00-01-0-680-00000], [soa].[00-01-0-710-00000], [soa].[00-01-0-720-00000], [soa].[00-01-0-730-00000]} ON ROWS
from [cubExecution]
```

The OLAP is like this :

[image]

**update :**

here is the field in report designer :

[image]

So how to make the field to be of type `Double` ?

Comment: It's not clear what do you need: what filed are you referring?

Comment: the field representing the measure for the column 2013.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the first item in the field is being used to decide the type.

You could confirmif that is definitely the case by running the following and if both are now type double then yes that top empty cell creates the object type:

```
select 
  NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize(
      Crossjoin(
       {[Measures].[engagement]},     
         Union(
           Union(
             Union(
               Union(
                 Crossjoin(
                   {[structure].[All structures]}, 
                   {[temps].[2016]}
                 ), 
                 Crossjoin(
                   {[structure].[All structures]}, 
                   {[temps].[2015]}
                 )
               ), 
               Crossjoin(
                 {[structure].[All structures]}, 
                 {[temps].[2014]}
               )
             ), 
             Crossjoin(
               {[structure].[All structures]}, 
               {[temps].[2013]}
             )
           ), 
           Crossjoin(
             {[structure].[All structures]}, 
             {[temps].[2012]}
           )
         )
       )
     ) ON COLUMNS,
     NON EMPTY 
       {
        //[soa].[00-01-0-030-00000], //<<commented out
        [soa].[00-01-0-100-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-120-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-680-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-710-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-720-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-730-00000]} ON ROWS
  from [cubExecution];
```

Empty space is generally your friend within a cube and a query as it makes things execute quickly, so forcing empty to zero is not really good practice, but you could change empty to zero - but you will now get lots of columns cells appearing that did not exist before - but your typing problem may be fixed?

```
WITH 
 [Measures].[engagementX] AS 
    CoalesceEmpty([Measures].[engagement],0)
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize(
      Crossjoin(
       {[Measures].[engagementX]},     
         Union(
           Union(
             Union(
               Union(
                 Crossjoin(
                   {[structure].[All structures]}, 
                   {[temps].[2016]}
                 ), 
                 Crossjoin(
                   {[structure].[All structures]}, 
                   {[temps].[2015]}
                 )
               ), 
               Crossjoin(
                 {[structure].[All structures]}, 
                 {[temps].[2014]}
               )
             ), 
             Crossjoin(
               {[structure].[All structures]}, 
               {[temps].[2013]}
             )
           ), 
           Crossjoin(
             {[structure].[All structures]}, 
             {[temps].[2012]}
           )
         )
       )
     ) ON COLUMNS,
     NON EMPTY 
       {
        [soa].[00-01-0-030-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-100-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-120-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-680-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-710-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-720-00000], 
        [soa].[00-01-0-730-00000]} ON ROWS
  from [cubExecution];
```